# How can I enable all possible Facebook notifications to be received by email?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

I would like to first enable all possible email notifications by Facebook (including all my Groups and Pages) to then subsequently and selectively turn those off that I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/154884887910599):

> > You can't turn off notifications entirely, but you can adjust what you're notified about and how you're notified.
> >     Keep in mind that if the notification is from an app, you can block the app on Facebook. To block an app, navigate to its [about page](https://www.facebook.com/help/222935611077438). At the bottom-left corner, click **Block App**.
>
> Email notifications are Facebook updates that you receive via email. To adjust your email notifications from Facebook:
>
> 1. Click *down arrow symbol* at the top-right corner and select **Settings**.
> 2. Click **Notifications** on the left.
> 3. Select **Email**.
> 4. From here, you can adjust your email notifications.

In your case choose *All notifications, except the ones you unsubscribe from* option. And later when you wish to not receive some specific email notification just unsubscribe from email.